# Pass Spark SQL function name as parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to pass a Spark SQL function name to my defined function in Scala.

I am trying to get same functionality as:

```
myDf.agg(max($"myColumn"))
```

my attempt doesn't work:

```
def myFunc(myDf: DataFrame, myParameter: String): Dataframe = {
  myDf.agg(myParameter($"myColumn"))
}
```

Obviously it shouldn't work as I'm providing a string type I am unable to find a way to make it work.
Is it even possible?

Edit:
I have to provide sql function name (and it can be other aggregate function) as parameter when calling my function.

```
myFunc(anyDf, max) or myFunc(anyDf, "max")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`agg` also takes a `Map[String,String]` which allows to do what you want:

```
def myFunc(myDf: DataFrame, myParameter: String): DataFrame = {
  myDf.agg(Map("myColumn"->myParameter))
}
```

example:

```
val df = Seq(1.0,2.0,3.0).toDF("myColumn")

myFunc(df,"avg")
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+-------------+
|avg(myColumn)|
+-------------+
|          2.0|
+-------------+
```

Comment: Nice one, does exactly whats required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}

val df = Seq((1, 2, 12),(2, 1, 21),(1, 5, 10),(5, 3, 9),(2, 5, 4)).toDF("a","b","c")

def myFunc(df: DataFrame, f: Column): DataFrame = {
  df.agg(f)
}

myFunc(df, max(col("a"))).show
+------+
|max(a)|
+------+
|     5|
+------+
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, I wan't clear enough but only the name of the aggregate function can be supplied as parameter.